# Emacs move to next whitespace

Tags: emacs

In emacs there are the functions `forward-word` and `backward-word`. Are there also functions which move the point to the next/last whitespace?

Comment: Isn't this for a lot of cases equivalent?
What is the use case there a different functionality is needed?

Comment: For example if a have a generalized word like `\a_command_with_special-characters`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify the syntactical properties of characters using the `modify-syntax-entry` function (`C-h f`  `modify-syntax-entry` in emacs for more info):

For instance, if you are writing .tex documents, you might add the following to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook
 'TeX-mode-hook
 '(lambda ()
    (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
    (modify-syntax-entry ?- "w")
))
```

This tells emacs to treat `_` and `-` as "word" characters when you are in TeX mode, thus forward-word and backward-word will do what you want.

Comment: Does this break emacs packages that rely on what a word is?

Comment: @ritchie It will only modify the syntax table for the chosen mode, so will have limited scope for mischief. I'd expect most packages to behave fine (I use this trick in other modes, not TeX), so "try it and find out"?  :)

Answer (score 11):

Use `forward-whitespace` to advance by spaces, tabs or newlines.  Multiple spaces are treated as one delimiter.  With a negative argument, go backwards by that number of whitespaces.

Comment: Any idea how to advance to the first whitespace after a block of text, without skipping any?  forward-whitespace seems to skip to the end of the line when I have trailing spaces on a line.  I really just want to find the first trailing space. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Dave : (lambda () (forward-whitespace) (forward-whitespace -1))

Comment: Any idea how to do `backward-whitespace`?

Comment: @Noah See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26098/7059 for how to define `backward-whitespace`.

Comment: @Noah `(forward-whitespace -1)` or `C-u -1 M-x forward-whitespace`